# CSS IE6 case - inner div doesn't fit in 100%

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have one big container (div) and one header div inside of it. It should fit the container in 100% of its width. And it does, everywhere instead of IE6 (it does even in IE7).

HTML code:

```
<body>
   <header>
      <table summary="Displaying something">
         <tr class="first-row">
            <th>Fdsfdsf:</th>
            <td>fdjsklf</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>dfdsfdsf:</th>
            <td>vcxvcx</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>FDSfjdsklf</th>
            <td>FDsjfkdsj</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </header>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
* {
    margin:                 0;
    padding:                0;
}
html {
    font:                   62.5% verdana, geneva, sans-serif;
    line-height:            1.125em;
    background-color:       silver;
    text-align:             center;
}
body {
    background-color:       white;
    width:                  79%;
    min-width:              1024px;
    max-width:              1920px;
    margin:                 3% auto;
    text-align:             left;
}
header {
    padding:                1em;
    border-bottom:          1px solid silver;
    text-align:             center;
}
header table {
    margin:                 0 auto;
}
header table tr {
    font-size:              0.8em;
}
header table .first-row {
    font-size:              1em;
}
header table th {
    font-weight:            normal;
    padding:                0 10px 0 0;
    text-align:             right;
}
header table .first-row th {
    font-weight:            bold;       
}
header table .first-row td, header table .first-row th {
    border-bottom:          1px dotted silver;
}
```

Sorry for the length of the code. To check the header size I added bottom margin. It fits the left side of the outer container perfectly. And as the header doesn't have width set in the file it should fit the outer div also to the right. However there exist a gap on the right side. The end of the border is a little bit (about 20px) distanced from the right side, so it's too short.

Can you see the problem? I tried everything, the only thing that works is setting width: 100% in the header. However because of the padding it is too long in other browsers...

Comment: Is there a reason you need to support IE6? Going as far back as IE7 should be fine most of the time. Some sites don't even bother with lower than IE9 anymore.

Comment: Why support IE6? I am not saying don't ask your question; perhaps you have no choice. But seeing "IE6" in 2012 is quite surprising, and makes me curious.

Comment: From what I've read about 80% of people using IE < 9...I thought looking good in IE6 is a necessity.

Comment: http://www.ie6countdown.com/ Canadian users 0.7% American users 0.4% UK users 0.9% Unless your major user base is in India, Japan or Vietnam... supporting IE6 is a waste and even in those countries the percentage of users is below 5% It's much like supporting 800x600 resolution, the vast majority of users don't use that resolution any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If adding 100% to the `header` works, you can use:

```
header {
    padding:                1em;
    border-bottom:          1px solid silver;
    text-align:             center;
    width:                  100%;
    box-sizing:             border-box; /* that's the magic */
}
```

Padding will be included in the total lenght in later browsers thanks to the power of [**box-sizing**](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

---

As they're already pointing out in the comments, [unless you live in China](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) you can probably ignore IE7 and below.

Comment: And BTW...I'm curious why setting 100% width of the div inside another div makes it too wide...

Comment: Yes it isn't, but you said "only thing that works is setting width: 100% in the header". This way you won't cause scrollbars to appear in newer browsers.

Comment: @user1615069: My guess is because of the padding.